# How do I properly call netapi32!NetSessionEnum()?

Tags: winapi, go

I'v been trying to play with netapi32.dll, but I'm having mixed results.

The following works as expected

```
type SERVER_INFO_101 struct {
      PlatformID   uint32
      Name         *uint16
      VersionMajor uint32
      VersionMinor uint32
      Type         uint32
      Comment      *uint16
}


func NetServerGetInfo() {
      info := &SERVER_INFO_101{}
      ret, _, err := procNetServerGetInfo.Call(0, 101, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&info)))
      if ret != 0 {
              log.Fatal(err)
      }
      spew.Dump(info)
}
```

However, I'm not sure why info has to have & inside the unsafe.Pointer also.

The following does not work, and I can't seem to find out why. No error codes get thrown. Neither the struct or variables gets filled out.

```
type SESSION_INFO_10 struct {
      Cname    *uint16
      Username *uint16
      Time     uint32
      IdleTime uint32
}

func NetSessionEnum() {
      info := &SESSION_INFO_10{}
      var prefmaxlen int32 = -1
      var entriesread uint32
      var totalentries uint32
      var resumehandle uint32
      x, y, z := procNetSessionEnum.Call(0, 0, 0, 10, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(info)), uintptr(prefmaxlen), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&entriesread)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&totalentries)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&resumehandle)))
      fmt.Println(x, y, z)
      fmt.Println(entriesread, totalentries)
      spew.Dump(info)
}
```

Comment: Please pick an appropriate title for your question. Your current version is completely unrelated to the question you are asking. Also, don't add tags to the title; questions can be tagged explicitly.

Comment: For the first half, no, the `unsafe.Pointer` conversion should not need a `&`. In fact, having the `&` will end up trampling over unintended memory, and because you're using `unsafe` the compiler won't yell at you! What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @andlabs if I remove the `&` nothing gets written to the struct.  It looks like kostix down below explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…because you're not supposed to pass a pointer to *your* memory block there—to cite [the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525382):

> This buffer is allocated by the system and must be freed using the NetApiBufferFree function.

The type of that pointer is misleading but you're supposed to pass a pointer to a pointer there, something like this:

```
func NetSessionEnum() {
      var pinfo *SESSION_INFO_10
      var prefmaxlen int32 = -1
      var entriesread uint32
      var totalentries uint32
      var resumehandle uint32
      x, y, z := procNetSessionEnum.Call(0, 0, 0, 10,
          uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pinfo)), uintptr(prefmaxlen),
          uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&entriesread)),
          uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&totalentries)),
          uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&resumehandle)))
      fmt.Println(x, y, z)
      fmt.Println(entriesread, totalentries)
      spew.Dump(info)
}

// Now use `*pinfo.Cname` etc
// Don't forget to later call `NetApiBufferFree()` on that pointer.
```

What happens here:

1. The variable `pinfo` is a pointer to a value of type `SESSION_INFO_10`.
2. You take the address of the memory block occupied by the value kept in that variable (which is a pointer) and pass it to `NetSessionEnum()`.
3. That function allocates the buffer by itself and writes its address to the memory block pointed to by the address you have passed to the function.

   Since you've passed an address of the `pinfo` variable, the address of the buffer ends up being written into the variable `pinfo`.
4. You then use that address stored in `pinfo` to access the memory allocated by `NetSessionEnum()`.

That's called "double indirection" and is used in quite many places of Win32 API. Please read the manual page and study the code example it includes.

**Update:** as it turned out, there were more problems with the original code so I've took time to provide full solution—[here](https://gist.github.com/kostix/50830f62972311afa43a) is the gist (tested with Go 1.6 amd64 and i386 on Windows XP 32-bit, Windows 2003 R2 64-bit and Windows 8.1 64-bit).

Comment: I've tried what you stated above and the struct is just nil, nothing gets written to it.  Also entriesread, totalentries are still 0, it looks like nothing gets written to those values either.

Comment: And what are `x` and `z`? (Really they should be `ret` and `err` as you have in your first code block.)

Comment: 0 Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

Comment: @b00stfr3ak, there are more problems with your code than it appears on the first sight. I've got a 80% working solution as of now, will try to post a gist in a couple of hours.

Comment: @b00stfr3ak, here we go--please see the updated answer.

Comment: @andlabs, to my knowledge, with Win32 API at least, only the first return value is used, and that's what function returned. One should consult MSDN to check what sense to made of it--typically it can be a `BOOL` with 0 and 1 standing for false and true or `HRESULT` .

Comment: @kostix I know that already; I was just pointing out what the conventional variable names should be. I'm not sure why the middle parameter is there; the stdcall calling convention does not seem to return two values. SOme other OS?

Comment: @kostix this is the output of the the code linked: `2016/03/09 21:48:27 []`

I tried to add some println to see if entriesread or totalentries had any values and both returned 0

Comment: @b00stfr3ak, that's normal: on all non-server Windows I tried it returns 0 entries; on a server instance I got 30-something sessions. You can try connecting to a Windows share on your box from another machine to see that session listed.

Comment: @b00stfr3eak, if you wanted to enumerate *logged in users* instead you picked wrong facet of the Win32 API -- look at Windows Terminal Services (WTS) instead.

Comment: @andlabs, I think so, yes. Go works on "weird" systems including Plan9 which, for instance, has string as the "exit code" of a process ;-) I think they provided for common ground where applicable.

Comment: @kostix yes, but Plan 9 also has a different syscall package and no shared libraries :) Still interesting...